# Is is possilbe to create and sign a single domain cert with a wildcard cert?

Tags: tls

Given a CA signed SSl wildcard cert for say `*.example.com`, is it possible to create a single domain cert for say `foo.example.com` and sign that with the wildcard cert?

If so, how? (Linux tools preferred.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter if the certificate you use for signing is wildcard or not. What matters is that the CA flag of the certificate is true, which means that it can be used for signing other certificates.

You usually cannot buy certificates with CA flag true (at least unless you have lots of money and security). But if you are building your own certificate hierarchy there are enough resources out there which will help you.